# Quick Question on Supremums and Infimums

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I was wondering if anyone could help me grasp this question very quickly. So is does the set of integers have any infimums or supremums? I was thinking no as it goes to -infinity and +infinity while also being closed under addition. Thank you!

Comment: 1 is inf. infinity is not a number.

Comment: A set, if it has any supremum, can have only one. Similarly for infimum.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [least-upper-bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) states that any non-empty set of real numbers *that has an upper bound* must have a least upper bound in real numbers. Since $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb R$ is not bonded above, it cannot have a least upper bound. Similar logic applies for the lower bound.

Also, the plural forms are *infima* and *suprema*.

Comment: The use of Latin-form plurals for *supremum* and *infimum* is not universal; for example, https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/320/notes/supinf.pdf. I would much rather have someone add an 's' here to express a plural rather than delete the final 's' from *vertices* or *matrices* in an attempt to write a singular.